# Does linux provide any DEBUG api, like windows?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, extend

Windows provides a set of Debug API's so that the program can stop at certain positions and dump corresponding information, to write our own debugger, etc, like [Using DebugActiveProcess and WaitForDebugEvent seems to hang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923724/using-debugactiveprocess-and-waitfordebugevent-seems-to-hang)

My question is, does linux also provide such a series of debug api so that we can easily write our own debugger, or extend gdb, not having to gain knowledge about linux kernel, etc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is `ptrace()` user-space API in Linux (and some Unix) to implement debuggers (`gdb`) or tracers (`strace`):
* Man page of `ptrace()` in Linux http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html
* Wikipedia page on `ptrace` with history and overview in other UNIX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace

`ptrace()` can be used to stop/start process, get/set its registers, read and write its memory, doing single stepping or stop at every syscall.

Some basic information, memory maps and access to memory may be also exported to `/proc` special filesystem ([procfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs) as `/proc/self/` directory for current process and `/proc/PID` for process with pid of `PID`.

To [extend gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html#) you may use gdb commands or [gdb python API interface](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html) and [python commands](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-Commands.html), which are much easier (and sometimes more portable) than reimplementing basic parts of gdb.

Answer (score 0):

> does linux also provide such a series of debug api so that we can easily write our own debugger, or extend gdb, not having to gain knowledge about linux kernel, etc?

It is an *illusion* that one can easily write a Windows debugger without understanding the Windows kernel.

On Linux, the APIs provided are even harder to use and using `ptrace` to write a debugger almost certainly requires deep understanding of the kernel process management.